# How to access Custom service and dialog from custom confirm decorator

Tags: angular, decorator, mat-dialog

**How can I access to that singleton instances inside angular dependencies injections?**

I want to write custom decorator for confirm dialog using this way.

Decorator implementation:

```
import {NgplDialogConfirmModel, NgplDialogService} from '../dialog';
import {take} from 'rxjs/operators';

export function Confirmable(options?: NgplDialogConfirmModel, confirm = 'confirmService') {

  // our factory function will return our actual decorator function, but now we have
  // an actual options object to configure our alert box :)
  return (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    // the usual, caching the original implementation
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    // default values for our config, we’ll overwrite this with our options parameter

    console.log('target', target);
    console.log('propertyKey', propertyKey);
    console.log('descriptor.value', descriptor.value);
    console.log('target[confirm]', target[confirm]);
    const service: NgplDialogService = target &&  target[confirm];
    if (!service) {
     return descriptor;
    }
    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
      const dialogRef = service.confirm(options);
      return dialogRef
        .pipe(
          take(1)
        )
        .subscribe((confirmed: boolean) => {
          if (!!confirmed) {
            originalMethod.apply(this, ...args);
          }
        });
    };
    return descriptor;

  };

}
```

Used Here

```
  @Confirmable()
  confirmDelete(action): void {
    console.log('action', action);
  }
```

I have my own service integrate wit matDialog and confirm actions I use from everywhere.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NgplDialogService {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  public confirm(data: any= {}): Observable<boolean> {
    data.title = data.title || 'Confirm';
    data.message = data.message || 'Are you sure?';
    data.showCancel = data.showCancel || true;
    data.showIcon = data.showIcon || true;

    let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmComponent>;
    console.log('this.dialog', this.dialog);
    dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmComponent, {
      width: '480px',
      disableClose: true,
      data,
      backdropClass: 'confirm-backdrop-class',
      panelClass: 'confirm-panel-class'
    });
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
}
```

I tried some approach like Injertor.create and ReflectiveInjector(deprecated) and i can't access to my service instance.

I tried to access to confirmService injected inside component from decorator, but decorator executed before component dependency injection finish.
[image]

Comment: Can you make a runnable sample on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi  example run on stackblizt: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2bpgfc   , please check on stackblizt console , decorator function its executed before angular component initializacion, and do not have access to confirmService injected and needed to show dialog confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After read several time the same articles on internet, once again I read this one, https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/custom-typescript-decorators-using-rxjs-and-angular-services-6ddd1079f683, and I understood better that approach and I tried it in my stackbliz code, and Its works. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2bpgfc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

With the above comment i checked
. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2bpgfc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Enclose ...args with array in confirm decorator , else if you pass some arguments to the function to be called after decorator result,  you will be getting an error
Like This:

```
  originalMethod.apply(this, [...args]);
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImmrB.png)